# Using Meta Quest Pro for AR in Blender

Tags: vr

I wanted to know if there is a workflow/plugin to be able to use the AR pass through capabilities of the Meta Quest Pro in Blender? I'd like to build a dog sized robot that has basic animations, and be able to view using the quest pro pass through in my office in AR.

Attached a YT link below of what I am trying to achieve (starting at minute 1:36, not concerned about hand tracking) :

[image]

[AR ROBOT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A4AszH2ODXI&ab_channel=Varjo)

Below is a picture of a free blender robot that I am trying to have in AR using a Quest pro headset :

[image]

Thank you!!

Comment: Please include a screen capture of you Blender work directly in the question.  This is in addition to the reference to the video.

Comment: Hi @atomicbezierslinger - thanks for the reply :)

I've uploaded 2 images to my original post : First one is of the AR visual im trying to achieve and second is of the free robot that I have in my blend file that I would like to view in AR.

Hope this helps, thanks!